# Opening URL received from react POST request

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have successfully conducted an API call and I can see the correct response in my console. Is it possible to redirect my react app from the local hose to the url received (in this case the one called Gatewayurl under data) ? Any help is appreciated

```
{data: {…}, status: 202, statusText: "", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
config: {url: "yahoo.com", method: "post", data: "{"referenceNumber":"string"}", headers: {…}, transformRequest: Array(1), …}
data:
GatewayUrl: "google.com"   //THIS IS THE URL I WANT TO REDIRECT TO
referenceNumber: "C1234"
__proto__: Object
headers: {content-type: "application/json;charset=UTF-8"}
request: XMLHttpRequest {readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, onreadystatechange: ƒ, …}
status: 202
statusText: ""
__proto__: Object
```

This is my code:

```
axios.post('https::/yahoo.come/send', data, config)
        .then((data)=>{
            console.log(data);  
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        })
```

Comment: You could use `window.location.href` or `window.open` to open a new page.

Answer (score 1):

Use `window.location.href`

```js
...
.then((data)=>{
     console.log(data);  
     window.location.href = 'http://google.com'
})
...
```

Comment: if i do  window.location.href = data.GatewayUrl; then nothing happens and the output seems to dissapear from the console as well. The API does not actually redirect to google that is just a placeholder

Comment: as long as ur url is correct it shd work .... make sure that your gateway url is a full url i.e. `http://<your gateway url>`

Comment: yes, thats why im confused to why its not working, the url is correct :(